# Extract data from text file in formatted/sequential way

Tags: c++, file, structure, store

I have a file .txt with this structure:

> 000010109000010309000010409

Where i need to read like this:

```
00001 01 09
00001 03 09
00001 04 09
```

I have a structure in this way:

```
struct A{
    string number // first 5 numbers
    int day; // 2 numbers
    int month; // last 2 numbers
};
```

I tried in this way.
But dont work.

```
    char number[6];
    char day[3];
    char monthes[3];
    ifstream read("file.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        read.get(number,6);
        structure[i].number= number;
        read.get(day,3);
        structure[i].day= atoi(day);
        read.get(month,3);
        structure[i].month= atoi(month);
    }
```

How read and store the datas from the file to this structure?
And how compare if the number have in the same month many days.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why `int*` in `struct A` ?

Comment: Is there anything that you have attempted? We need to find a way to convert this question into something that will be useful for others also.

Comment: The iomanip `setw` shows promise with a normal `cin` or with `istringstream` after `getline`. What problems have you encountered?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
A a;
char x[6], y[3], z[3];
fscanf(fp, "%5s%2s%2s", x, y, z);
a.number = string(x);
a.day = atoi(y);
a.month = atoi(z);
```

**EDIT**:

It is valid C++ code (with `cstdio` and `cstdlib`), but if you want some **C++** version, you could try something like this

```
// read from file.txt
std::ifstream inFile("file.txt", std::ios::in);
char number[6], day[3], month[3];
int cnt = 0;
while (inFile.get(number, 6) && inFile.get(day, 3) && inFile.get(month, 3)) {
    // Let's assume that structure[] is array of struct A
    structure[cnt].number = number;
    structure[cnt].day = atoi(day);
    structure[cnt].month = atoi(month);
    ++cnt;
}
// store to file2.txt
std::ofstream outFile("file2.txt", std::ios::out);
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i) {
    outFile << structure[i].number << ' ' << structure[i].day << ' ' << structure[i].month << std::endl;
    // If you need fixed-width for day/month, use std::setw and std::setfill
}
// compare first two
if (cnt >= 2) {
    if (structure[0].number == structure[1].number &&
        structure[0].month  == structure[1].month  &&
        structure[0].day    == structure[1].day) {
            std::cout << "Same!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Different!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `FILE` and `fopen` in a C++ program.

Comment: This is C, i need C++

Comment: How do you know this isn't from `<cstdio>`?

Comment: This is still valid c++ code.  It may not be the prettiest or idiomatic, but it still compiles.

Comment: While that is pedantically accurate, there seems to be little reason to teach this way.

Comment: If you see my edit, is the same my code, but dont work, the array of the struct is empty. If you want see all the code, https://pastebin.com/cX4RDHbY

Comment: @Master-Antonio your pastebin code won't work, because you didn't call `estraiDati`.

Comment: @0xrgb copy only the first number, month and day. Is like that the file is stopped and dont flow/move to the next character.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `stringstream` here as an example but the same will work with `fstream`. Convert *number*, *day* and *month* from `char` arrays to required data types as necessary (all are '\0' terminated)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {

    std::string s = "000010109000010309000010409";
    std::istringstream iss(s);

    char number[6], day[3], month[3];
    while (iss.get(number, 6) && iss.get(day, 3) && iss.get(month, 3))
        std::cout << number << " " << day << " " << month << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/tyBShW

```
00001 01 09
00001 03 09
00001 04 09
```